# Printing out a HashMap using an Another HashMap's key as values

Tags: java

If I have a HashMap such as

```
{opst=post pots stop spot tops opts,
 art=rat tar art,
 glos=slog,
 gopr=gorp,
 fgor=frog,
 aprt=trap tarp part,
 dgo=dog god,
 act=act cat tac,
 fglo=flog golf}
```

and a HashMap such as

```
{opst=otsp, art=atr, fgor=grof, aprt=arpt, dgo=gdo, act=atc}
```

How would I use the second HashMap as my key to print out something like...

```
arpt part tarp trap
atc act cat tac
atr art rat tar
gdo dog god
grof frog
otsp opts post pots spot stop tops
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your first `HashMap` is called `firstMap` and the second is `secondMap`, then navigate through the keys of `secondMap` to print the values stored on first map. Here's a code sample:

```
for (String secondMapKey : secondMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(firstMap.get(secondMapKey));
}
```

Another option may be iterating through the entries of `secondMap` of the second map and get the keys (in case you also need the value of `secondMap` along to the key):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : secondMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(firstMap.get(entry.getKey()) + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Use keySet() directly ;-)

Comment: @Vakh I was updating the answer to include it. I'm more used to the first way.

Comment: It does not really matter. It is just a bit cleaner IMO just to get what you need.

Comment: @user3287300 that's possible in the second option.

Comment: @Vakh OP deleted his/her comment about using the value as well.